# Parsing multiple JSON files with Swift using one Decodable Struct

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have several JSON feeds, for this example let's these two ([A](http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/citi-bike-nyc) & [B](https://nextbike.net/maps/nextbike-official.json?city=532)). Both have different structures but both have an array of structures identifying the elements I'd like to parse, the bike stations.

I'd like to avoid creating a different class for each JSON feed I have to parse and if possible parse the underlying array of structures with the same `Decodable` `struct`. The definition of my model is as follows,

```
struct Places: Decodable {
    var name: String
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
    let id: String
    let bikes: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case lat = "latitude"
        case lng = "longitude"
        case id
        case bikes = "free_bikes"
    }
}
```

This model would only serve for one JSON feed and for each I'd have to create different `CodingKeys`. This is also a problem because the intermediate elements differ from feed to feed.

What I currently have is different parsers used on each feed. My app uses the array of `Places` to add pins on a map so the defined `struct` **has** to be the same for every feed that I parse. This is not a scalable solution for me and I'd like to ask if the following is correct,

1. Can I have only one parser that fit all my needs?
2. Can I have only one parser with different root elements and the same `Places` struct in the end?
3. Can I build a parser that only accesses the intermediate elements defined in the `Places` structure and "forget" about the top level differences between the feeds

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015691/parsing-different-json-feeds-in-swift-to-the-same-decodable-struct) only for the inner elements. While that is still true I now have problems parsing all the documents only to get the array of `Places`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing right off the top, I would suggest rename your `Places` struct to `Place` (singular). I would also suggest using the full names for `latitude` and `longitude`.

On to the specific questions:

I think `1` & `2` would be possible, but you might end up with much less maintainable code.

1. Yes. Doable with the caveat above.
2. Yes. Challenging, because in the NextBike & CitiBike examples you provided, the IDs are of different types (String `id` in CitiBike and Int `uid`), so would need to be mapped.
3. No, I don't think so, because you'll still need to do the type mapping mentioned above in `2`.

For maintainability, I would suggest creating `Decodable` structs/classes for each of the *types* of feeds with (possibly) embedded structs/classes to support hierarchy and then provide a map to `[Place]`. You can use a protocol to enforce compliance.

```swift
protocol PlacesProviding {
    var places: [Place] { get }
}

struct Place: Decodable {
    var name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let id: String
    let bikes: Int
```

Using your NextBike & CitiBike examples, you might want to be able to do something like:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let nyc = decoder.decode(NYCitiBike.self, from: citiBikeNYC)
let nb = decoder.decode(NextBike.self, from: nextBike)

var places = [Place]()
places.append(contentsOf: nb.places)
places.append(contentsOf: nyc.places)
print(places.count)
```

Here are example `Decodable` `PlaceProviding` objects that support this. The structure of these make very clear the expected structure of the associated feed and make it easy to surface additional properties from a feed. This improves maintainability, especially in the longer term.

```swift
struct NYCitiBike: Decodable, PlacesProviding {

    struct Network: Decodable {
        let stations: [Station]
    }

    struct Station: Decodable {
        var name: String
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double
        let id: String
        let bikes: Int

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name
            case latitude
            case longitude
            case id
            case bikes = "free_bikes"
        }

    }

    let network: Network

    var stations: [Station] { return network.stations }
    var places: [Place] {
        stations.map { Place(name: $0.name, latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude, id: $0.id, bikes: $0.bikes) }
    }
```

```swift
struct NextBike: Decodable, PlacesProviding {

    struct Country: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let cities: [City]
    }

    struct City: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let places: [Station]
    }

    struct Station: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let lat: Double
        let lng: Double
        let uid: Int
        let bikes: Int
    }

    let countries: [Country]
    var stations: [Station] {
        return countries
            .flatMap { $0.cities }
            .flatMap { $0.places }
    }
    var places: [Place] {
        stations.map { Place(name: $0.name, latitude: $0.lat, longitude: $0.lng, id: String($0.uid), bikes: $0.bikes) }
    }
```